# Short to bytes in c (Unix related)

Tags: c, unix

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{  
   short x = 768;
   printf("%04x", x);

   return 0;
}
```

This prints

```
0300
```

But when I redirect this output to a file called temp. I then xxd temp...

```
3033 3030
```

Why can I not get xxd temp, to print

```
0300
```

How would I do that? I can't print out a char, there is no char that has the ASCII value of 768?

Comment: Convert the hex value to a string, then write the string to the file?

Comment: the printf() output the value in hex (but since it is printf() the hex values are actually ascii characters of the hex representation of the number,  this results in the contents of the file being 30333030.  suggest modifying the printf() statement to output what you actually want to see

Comment: "cat temp" instead of xxd, and you'll see that you have written 0300 in ASCII, which is four bytes: 0x30, 0x33, 0x30, and 0x30.

Comment: Thanks, I see now. What string would give 0300?

Answer (score 5):

Because the output of your program is **characters**, not true, raw binary numbers.

In your example, what you see printed as the **character** '0' is actually stored as a **binary** 0x30.

If you want to output true binary data, use `fwrite()`.

Answer (score -1):

suggest using printf( "%4.4d", x );

When using xxd there are two columns of output

on the left the original number '0300'
on the right the hex value      '30333030'